# Elementary won't shut down with custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: release-hera, keyboard-shortcuts, shutdown

The custom keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+k.  After using this shortcut, it takes 30-60 seconds for everything to shutdown.

Lately when I do this, the screen will just show the elementary logo on a black background, at which point I have to use the laptop power button to shut it down (can't open terminal, etc.)

FYI I use a Lenovo Ideapad 3, run elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera only, and there are no other distros on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply bound the shortcut to `shutdown` the default behavior for that is to schedule a shutdown in 60 seconds. You probably want to bind to the command:

```
shutdown now
```